# why can not open gallery in release apk flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i have app on flutter .i added permission in manifest, and add lib in pubspec.yaml

the camera is work fine both debug and release, the gallery works fine with debug but not open in release.
lib image_picker: ^0.6.7+14

my code

```
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  List<File> images = List<File>();

 Future chooseImage() async {

    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    setState(() {
      if(pickedFile != null){
        images.add(File(pickedFile.path));
      }else{
     
      }

    });
   


  }
```

can some one tell me how can slove it
thanks

Comment: which pkg you are using ?

Comment: @AwiasRehman import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

Comment: `XFile image = await _picker.pickImage(...).          using this method and add permission

Comment: Awias Rehman  is still not work fine